# Get frame of Navigation Bar with UINavigationBar appearance

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uinavigationbar, uiappearance

Sorry for simple question, but following code:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage
    imageNamed:@"backgroundNavigationBar.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
CGRect frame = [[UINavigationBar appearance] frame];
NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGRect(frame));
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] addSubview: view];
```

gives me

```
{{0, 0}, {0, 0}}
```

How to correctly get frame of current Navigation Bar with actual sizes, i.e. 320x64?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
CGRect frame = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid your code won't work the way you'd like :/

The appearance proxy is certainly not for adding subviews !

You can only ever edit properties through UIAppearance that are marked as '`UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR`' in the header files !

The compiler lets you write your code, because `+ (instancetype)appearance` actually returns a proxy object of the class.

The actual view you want to add a subview to does not have anything to do with that proxy. `UIAppearance` looks at the proxy object, and copies over only the `UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR` marked properties when a new view is created.

Please read this https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

and this http://nshipster.com/uiappearance/ 
, it will give you a great overview of how `UIAppearance` is used.